# My cucumber freezes on "Using the default profile..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, cucumber, freeze, osx-leopard

My cucumber freezes on the statement "Using the default profile..." when I *first* run the `cucumber` command. I can't even hit Ctrl - C to break out, I have to **close the terminal tab completely and restart Mac OS X**. I tried to remove `rerun.txt`with no luck. It's very intermittent. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's where it gets stuck:

```
cucumber --verbose
Using the default profile...
Code:
  * features/support/env.rb
```

This is my system info:

```
ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin9.8.0]

cucumber --version
0.8.5

About your application's environment
Ruby version              1.8.7 (i686-darwin9.8.0)
RubyGems version          1.6.2
Rails version             2.1.0
Active Record version     2.1.0
Action Pack version       2.1.0
Active Resource version   2.1.0
Action Mailer version     2.1.0
Active Support version    2.1.0
Edge Rails revision       83480b0ca0647bb60f08e03ce12e3cf5071b1f0d
Environment               development
Database adapter          postgresql
Database schema version   20110530174319

sw_vers | grep 'ProductVersion:' | grep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*'
10.5.8 #Mac OS X version
```

Comment: Can you post your `features/support/env.rb`, maybe there is something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here I believe is `rvm`. If I run `cucumber` with the wrong `rvm`, I believe this is causing the freeze. When I switch to proper Ruby version using `rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p334` immediately and running `cucumber`, it works.